# Windows 8 JS & html5 app - foreach within template

Tags: templates, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

How do I loop thru items in a `WinJS.Binding.Template` within my `WinJS.UI.ListView` control?

My data:

```
{ category: 'Sports', 
  items: [
    { title: 'soccer'}, { title: 'tennis'}
  ] 
}
```

What I **want** to do in my template:

```
<div id="myTmpl" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display:none">
  <h1 data-win-bind="innerText: category"></h1>
  <div data-win-REPEATER="each: items">
    <span data-win-bind="innerText: title"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to nest the details of the items, I would recommend that you look at my answer to another question, which is very similar:

[WinJS ListView and Template Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337489/winjs-listview-and-template-binding/13337787#13337787)

This has all the essential details.

That stated, theres no reason you cant integrate JQuerys templates here - you just need to find a way for them to work with the WinJS template / control contract.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-basic-usage-sample-fcc451db

Normally the loop is automatically (it will do based on the datasource information)

```
<div id="listView" 
        class="win-selectionstylefilled"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
        data-win-options="{ 
            itemDataSource: myData.dataSource, 
            itemTemplate: myTmpl, 
            selectionMode: 'none', 
            tapBehavior: 'none', 
            swipeBehavior: 'none', 
            layout: { type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout } 
        }"
    ></div>
```

Comment: I would not recommend using the listview for basic list scenarios. The List View control is a complex, rich and fully featured control. But, if you just want a simple list of test items, then it's completely overkill.

Comment: Even if you believe it's a complex control, it's the control suggested by all microsoft engineers in WOWZAPP - Hackathon for Windows. The idea is to make easier the development in WINJS, he does not need to write lot of code (as you suggested) to do something already implemented. If listview is so "complex", why this  the solution being used/suggested in all the templates microsoft  provided to developers?

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/05/18/metro-introduction-to-the-winjs-listview-control.aspx

Comment: It's *Great* for a primary experience. But for placing a list inside a simple item template, it's silly. It's insane. And, on top of that, it's not supported -- you can't nest a listview in a listview.

Listview *is* a great control, but it is not the control for stamping things out. It is not the WinJS version of the WPF ItemsControl. It's too heavy.