# Data bind to a flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, windows-8, winjs

Is it possible to databind to a flexbox like you can with a WinJS.ListView?
I'm thinking of something like...

```
<!-- default.html -->
<div class="flexbox" style="display:-ms-flexbox;">
  <div class="itemA"></div>
  <div class="itemB"></div>
  <div class="itemC"></div>
</div>

/* JavaScript */
var aList = new WinJS.Binding.List([{name:"item 1"},{name:"item 2"},{name:"item 3"}]);
var flexbox = document.querySelector(".flexbox");
//is there some magic in WinJS to bind flexbox to aList???
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not (that I know of). The data binding in WinJS requires a control (the ListView) and an IListDataSource (like the WinJS.Binding.List you mentioned). You can pretty easily add items to the flexbox though using something like...

```
var flexbox = document.querySelector(".flexbox");
var myArray = [{name:"item 1"},{name:"item 2"},{name:"item 3"}];
myArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerText = item.name;
    flexbox.appendChild(div);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have a more complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337489/winjs-listview-and-template-binding/13337787#13337787 Note, that this won't react to the data changing in a `WinJS.Binding.List`, but should be "Easy" to add.