# Add a List of objects into a ViewModel

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I am trying to add this list into my view model in order to make some bindings a little bit simpler. However, I can't figure out the syntax in order to do so.

```
        var images = [
          { name: "Image 1", photo: "/images/image1.jpg" },
          { name: "Image 2", photo: "/images/image2.jpg" },
          { name: "Image 3", photo: "/images/image3.jpg" },
        ];

      var viewModel = {
          favorite: "",
       ...
      }
```

Comment: If you need to know how to access it in a data-win-bind check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089191/how-to-show-data-from-array-in-windows-8-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign images to `viewModel` like this:

```
  var viewModel = {
      favorite: "",
      images: images
  };
```

Then access them like this `viewModel.images`